# Propagate custom event to Parent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have got a custom event set up (see below), but when I listen for the event in my main class, and it gets dispatched from the child class, it never gets captured.

TRIED:

`this.b.addEventHandler(GameLaunchEvent.GAME_LAUNCH_EVENT, this.eventHandler)`

```
package com.thom.events 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author 
     */
    public class LaunchEventAbstract extends Event
    {
        public var parent:MovieClip;
        public function LaunchEventAbstract(type:String, parent:MovieClip = null) 
        {
            super(type, true);  
            this.parent = parent;
        }   
    }
}

package com.thom.events 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author
     */
    public class GameLaunchEvent extends LaunchEventAbstract 
    {
        public static const GAME_LAUNCH_EVENT:String = "GameLaunchEvent";
        public function GameLaunchEvent(parent:MovieClip = null) {
            trace("GameLaunchEvent");
            super(GAME_LAUNCH_EVENT, parent);
        }
    }

}

//example code
package {
   import com.thom.events.*;
   public class A extends MovieClip{
         public var b:B;
         public function A(){
              addEventListener(GameLaunchEvent.GAME_LAUNCH_EVENT, eventHandler);
              this.b = new B();
              addChild(b);
         }
         public function eventHandler(e:GameLaunchEvent){
             trace("Success");
         }
    }
}
package {
    import com.thom.events.*;
    public class B extends MovieClip{
         public function B() {
              dispatchEvent(new GameLaunchEvent(this));
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to pass the parent as a parameter , particularly if you intend to listen to your event in the parent itself. What you can do is pass a dispatcher as a parameter and let the dispatcher both dispatch & listen to the event.

```
package 
{
   import flash.display.MovieClip;
   import flash.events.Event;
   import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

   public class A extends MovieClip
   {
         public var b:B;
         private var _dispatcher:EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

         public function A()
         {
         _dispatcher.addEventListener('test', eventHandler);   
             this.b = new B(_dispatcher);
         }

         public function eventHandler(e:Event):void
         {
             trace("Success");
         }
    }
}


package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

    public class B extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _dispatcher:EventDispatcher;

        public function B(dispatcher:EventDispatcher) 
        {
            this._dispatcher = dispatcher;
            _dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new Event('test'));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late responses. The parent is needed to destroy it later on, but that is not relevant. Seems like a way to reach my goals.

Answer (score 3):

Event Bubbling is what you want:

```
Parent:
childClip.addEventListener('CUSTOM_EVENT', handler);

Child:
this.dispatchEvent(new Event('CUSTOM_EVENT', true, true));
```

This will propagate it up the display list.  The problem with listening to a loader directly is that it looks like this:

```
Loader
  - Content
```

Without bubbling you'd have to listen to the content directly, which is kind of pointless since you can't listen to it until the content has been loaded.

Comment: Strangely enough, this works with one of 2 classes. The other does not :(. But I sense that has to do with it not being loaded completly yet. +1 anyways :P

Comment: Make sure that in your childClip to do a dispatch the event ONLY after it's been added to the stage: so.  addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, dispatchInit)